# 'TemplateDoesNotExist' No consigo la solución

Tags: django, template, django-urls, django-templates

Estoy empezando en Django, pero estoy atascado con este problema

**Tengo esta estructura en mi 'Workspace' de VSCode**

```
- Proyecto1
    -__pycache__
    __init__.py
    asgi.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py     
    -templates
       miplantilla.html
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

**Estoy tratando de usar una plantilla que construí**

**urls.py**

```
from Proyecto1.views import salute

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('salute/', salute),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import render

class Persona(object):
    
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):

        self.nombre = nombre

        self.apellido = apellido

def salute(request): 

   p1=Persona('Peter', 'Parker')
   
   temas_del_curso = ['Plantillas', 'Modelos', 'Formularios', 'Vistas', 'Despliegue']

   fecha_de_hoy = datetime.datetime.now()

   return render(request, 'miplantilla.html', { 'nombre_persona' : p1.nombre, 'apellido_persona' : p1.apellido, 'fecha_de_hoy' : fecha_de_hoy, 'temas' : temas_del_curso })
```

**El curso me sugieren que copie la ruta del directorio donde esta guardada mi platilla**

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['C:/Users/machine/Desktop/Django/Proyecto1/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
}
```

**Alguien por favor ayudeme, he intentando de todo y aun no doy con la solución.
Tambien use la forma que sugiere Django `'DIRS': BASE_DIR / 'templates'` y no funciona**

Comment: ¿El curso no incluye el paso intermedio de crear una aplicación? En Django la carpeta de proyecto (`proyecto1` en tu caso) funciona como un punto de convergencia y gestión de las aplicaciones que defines. El paso que te falta es crear la aplicación, definir allí tus modelos, vistas y plantillas.

Comment: La configuracion de los templates se hace a nivel de tu carpeta raiz, por el motivo que tienes que verificar la forma en que lo pones, y en la configuracion en la constante templates DIRS no es recomendado que lo declares asi por motivos de compativilidad, la forma corta seria 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

Comment: @Sokkian en el curso no incluyen el paso de crear una aplicación, lo hace de forma directa. @cosmos multi coloque la carpeta 'templates' al mismo nivel que mi archivo 'manage.py' que coincide con el nivel de mi carpeta raíz (**Proyecto1**). Sin embargo el problema persiste. Intente con la forma `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` y el error continua...